# Image color detection

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect three colors blue , yellow and pink 
the blue and the yellow works fine but the pink nt working i dunno why 
but i think the problem in this line 
cv.Line(imdraw,pink[0],pink[1],(0,255,0),3,8,0)
can anyone help me !!

```
import cv
global imghsv
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setup("P8_11", GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup("P8_12", GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup("P8_13", GPIO.OUT)

def getthresholdedimg(im):

    '''this function take RGB image.Then convert it into HSV for easy colour detection and threshold it with yellow and blue part as white and all other regions as black.Then return that image'''
    global imghsv
    imghsv=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im),8,3)
    cv.CvtColor(im,imghsv,cv.CV_BGR2HSV)                # Convert image from RGB to HSV

    # A little change here. Creates images for blue and yellow (or whatever color you like).
    imgyellow=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im),8,1)
    imgblue=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im),8,1)
        imgpink=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im),8,1)

    imgthreshold=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im),8,1)

    cv.InRangeS(imghsv,cv.Scalar(20,100,100),cv.Scalar(30,255,255),imgyellow)   # Select a range of orange color
    cv.InRangeS(imghsv,cv.Scalar(100,100,100),cv.Scalar(120,255,255),imgblue)   # Select a range of blue color
    cv.InRangeS(imghsv,cv.Scalar(10,100,100),cv.Scalar(11,255,255),imgpink) # Select a range of pink color
        cv.Add(imgyellow,imgblue,imgthreshold)
    return imgthreshold

capture=cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
frame_size = cv.GetSize(frame)
test=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame),8,3)
img2=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame),8,3)
cv.NamedWindow("Real",0)
cv.NamedWindow("Threshold",0)
cv.NamedWindow("final",0)

#   Create two lists to store co-ordinates of blobs
blue=[]
yellow=[]
pink=[]

while(1):
    color_image = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    imdraw=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame),8,3)
    cv.SetZero(imdraw)
    cv.Flip(color_image,color_image,1)
    cv.Smooth(color_image, color_image, cv.CV_GAUSSIAN, 3, 0)
    imgyellowthresh=getthresholdedimg(color_image)
    cv.Erode(imgyellowthresh,imgyellowthresh,None,3)
    cv.Dilate(imgyellowthresh,imgyellowthresh,None,10)
    img2=cv.CloneImage(imgyellowthresh)
    storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
    contour = cv.FindContours(imgyellowthresh, storage, cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    points = [] 

#   This is the new part here. ie Use of cv.BoundingRect()
    while contour:
        # Draw bounding rectangles
        bound_rect = cv.BoundingRect(list(contour))
        contour = contour.h_next()
        print contour
        # for more details about cv.BoundingRect,see documentation
        pt1 = (bound_rect[0], bound_rect[1])
        pt2 = (bound_rect[0] + bound_rect[2], bound_rect[1] + bound_rect[3])
        points.append(pt1)
        points.append(pt2)
        cv.Rectangle(color_image, pt1, pt2, cv.CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1)

    #   Calculating centroids

        centroidx=cv.Round((pt1[0]+pt2[0])/2)
        centroidy=cv.Round((pt1[1]+pt2[1])/2)

    #   Identifying if blue or yellow blobs and adding centroids to corresponding lists 
        if (10<cv.Get2D(imghsv,centroidy,centroidx)[0]<11):
                        GPIO.output("P8_11", GPIO.HIGH)
                        GPIO.output("P8_12", GPIO.LOW)
                        GPIO.output("P8_13", GPIO.LOW)
            yellow.append((centroidx,centroidy))
        elif (100<cv.Get2D(imghsv,centroidy,centroidx)[0]<120):
                        GPIO.output("P8_11", GPIO.LOW)
                        GPIO.output("P8_12", GPIO.HIGH)
                        GPIO.output("P8_13", GPIO.LOW)
            blue.append((centroidx,centroidy))
        elif (10<cv.Get2D(imghsv,centroidy,centroidx)[0]<11):
                        GPIO.output("P8_11", GPIO.LOW)
                        GPIO.output("P8_12", GPIO.LOW)
                        GPIO.output("P8_13", GPIO.HIGH)
            blue.append((centroidx,centroidy))

#       Now drawing part. Exceptional handling is used to avoid IndexError. After drawing is over, centroid from previous part is #     removed from list by pop. So in next frame,centroids in this frame become initial points of line to draw.       
    try:
        cv.Circle(imdraw,yellow[1],5,(0,255,255))
        cv.Line(imdraw,yellow[0],yellow[1],(0,255,255),3,8,0)

        yellow.pop(0)
    except IndexError:
                GPIO.output("P8_11", GPIO.LOW)
        print "Just wait for yellow"

    try:
        cv.Circle(imdraw,blue[1],5,(255,0,0))
        cv.Line(imdraw,blue[0],blue[1],(255,0,0),3,8,0)
        blue.pop(0)         
    except IndexError:
                GPIO.output("P8_12", GPIO.LOW)
        print "just wait for blue"

        try:
        cv.Circle(imdraw,pink[1],5,(0,255,0))
        cv.Line(imdraw,pink[0],pink[1],(0,255,0),3,8,0)

        yellow.pop(0)
    except IndexError:
                GPIO.output("P8_13", GPIO.LOW)
        print "Just wait for pink"  
    cv.Add(test,imdraw,test)

    cv.ShowImage("Real",color_image)
    cv.ShowImage("Threshold",img2)
    cv.ShowImage("final",test)
    if cv.WaitKey(33)==1048603:
        cv.DestroyWindow("Real")
        cv.DestroyWindow("Threshold")
        cv.DestroyWindow("final")
        break
```

Comment: Try reducing the code you post to a minimum example. Anyways, it seems the formatting got corrupted, there is a `try:` statement without a body.

Answer (score 4):

Try to learn about `PIL.Image` module and use `getpixel((x,y))`.

Comment: when i type import image it gives me an error : import Image 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
ImportError: No module named Image

Comment: @user3262297 try import PIL.Image